# How can I start a screen session using a specific config file?

Tags: bash, config, gnu-screen

I would like to be able to start a screen session using a certain config file. I know that I can use `-c` and then the file path to the config file but if I do that, then the `sh` script I am using does not work. You can see the `sh` script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /media/kiancross/Minecraft_Server/1.6.4
screen -d -m -S MinecraftServer ./start.sh
screen -r MinecraftServer
```

I would have thought that I can do the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /media/kiancross/Minecraft_Server/1.6.4
screen -d -m -S -c MinecraftServer $HOME/config_file/mcserver.config ./start.sh
screen -r MinecraftServer
```

But then I get a message saying:

```
There is no screen to be resumed matching MinecraftServer.
```

After then checking to see if there is a screen session running it says that there are no screen sessions running

```
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-kiancross.
```

Does anybody know how I can do this so that I can use a custom config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command should be:

```
screen -d -m -S MinecraftServer -c $HOME/config_file/mcserver.config ./start.sh
```

The name of the screen session goes after `-S` and the path of the config file goes after `-c`. You inserted `-c` before the screen name.